# Maven how to show Junit test like on Eclipse IDE

Tags: maven, junit5

I would like to run Junit tests via maven command like having the test result
with the same graphical message that I can see using Eclipse IDE.

For example, if I run Junit test via Eclipse I can see this tree image:[image]

But, if I run the same tests via maven command line, I can see only the grand total result without details. 
For example:

[image]

There is a way to run maven command line tests and receive the test result like Eclipse IDE?
I use surefire plugin on my project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple answer to this: No. The question what exactly is needed in console for graphical purposes ? The output on command line tells you exactly what you need. It's succeeded or it has failed..

Comment: I would like to see the method name, the execution time, the green color if the test passed etc .. The same details as showed in the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Why do you need that on console? If it fails it will show the necessary information? BTW: Can you show the console output of your build? Which version of maven-surefire-plugin do you use? Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: I Used:  Maven-surefire-plugin.version2.22.2,  Junit5, Spring Boot: 2.6.6.  I like to see the result in console because it is more redable and contains method name executed with the test timing for singolar test.

Comment: First you should use maven-surefire-plugin 3.0.0-M6 that shows the nested classes for JUnit Jupiter but not on method names. The timing is only shown on the testclass/nested class level but not on the single test method. Furthermore I'm a bit stonished to see `TestInfo` as a paremeter in the test also you seemed to be using test suites?

Comment: What looks a bit strange to me is the consumed time of those tests ?

Comment: You can try this: https://github.com/fabriciorby/maven-surefire-junit5-tree-reporter